# Is it possible to share a sequence of messages in Slack?

Tags: slack

When I move cursor over a message it is highlighted with light grey and a share button (along with some others) appears, but it seems to allow to share only a single message.

Is it possible to share a series of consecutive messages, without sharing them one-by-one?

Answer (score 1):

No.

As a workaround I recommend sharing a screenshot of the full sequence along with a link to the start of the conversion.